# An error occurs when I press the button KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, kivy-language, kivymd

This is my first time writing on kivymd. An error occurred when clicking the button and the error points to the line **spell = Spelling()**. The error is  **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable**. On Windows, the same code works when clicked, but when running the same code on Ubuntu 22.04 it gives an error. I want to take text from **MDTextField** referring to its id **word = self.ids.word_input.text** but an error occurs. Here's my code:

main.py

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.core.spelling import Spelling
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

Builder.load_file('main.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):

    def press(self):

        spell = Spelling()
        spell.select_language('en_US')

        word = self.ids.word_input.text

        options = spell.suggest(word)
        x = ''
        for item in options:
            x = f'{x} {item}'

        self.ids.word_label.text = f'{x}'

class MyApp(MDApp):
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    title = 'Speller'
    
    def build(self):
        LabelBase.register('MyFont', fn_regular='UbuntuMono-Regular.ttf')

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'

        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<MyLayout>
    id: my_widget

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 50
        spacing: 30

        MDLabel:
            id: word_label
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            text: 'Enter a word'
            font_size: 32
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            color: ('#3D405B')

        MDTextField:
            id: word_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: 1
            font_size: 32
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            hint_text: 'Spell'

        MDRaisedButton:
            size_hint: (1, 0.5)
            font_size: 32.5
            text: 'Submit'
            font_name: 'MyFont'
            on_press: root.press()
```

I try to work with Id of MDTextField, but it's not helped. Please explain what the problem is or maybe there is another solution to this problem. Maybe I'm referencing the Id incorrectly

Comment: I understood why I didn't work in Ubuntu. I installed the python-enchant package on Windows, but didn't install Ubuntu, so the code didn't work. After installing the python-enchant package, everything worked.